# Create set of DropdowMenuItems from Hive List (Flutter & Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create this:

```
return DropdownButton(
    value: selectedValue,
    items: dropdownItems
);
```

By getting data from a Hive Box and looping through it to create the `DropdownMenuItem` but keep hitting errors, this is my loop code:

```
  List<LiveProject> lists = [];

  void getProjects() async {
    final box = await Hive.openBox<LiveProject>('project');
    setState(() {
      lists = box.values.toList();
    });
    List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>> menuItems = [
      for (var p in lists) {
        DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(p.title.toString()),value: p.id.toString()),
      }
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Error: A value of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'void'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DropdownMenuItem' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart').
    return menuItems;
           ^
```

LiveProject is my Model and I have a List declared in there the dat being insert is from JSON and is an array of objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
void getProjects()
```

do

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>> getProjects()
```